# Listing all failed targets

Tags: build, makefile, build-process, gnu-make, target

I'm attempting to build a large legacy code base that has troubles building under new toolchain. In order to speed up fixing problems, I run

```
make -k
```

to build everything that can be built, so that I can later focus on unbuildable stuff. But even then a single `make` takes a minute to figure out the next problem to work on (this code base uses a tangled mess of Makefiles which take ages to parse).

Is there any way to list all targets that failed during a single `make -k` run?

Answer (score 1):

I'd redirect the `make -k` output to a file and then look for the error patterns in it. I use `vim` and I'm typically looking for these:

```
make:\ \*\*\*
\*\*\*\ \[
```

A (custom) log parser can be written as well as needed.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll add that `make` prints these errors to stderr, so I can ignore stdout when grepping. will probably be good enough for my purposes, but not having good machine-parseable output is not a good sign…

Comment: For this particular task (errors from make itself) it's ok with just stderr, but if you want to go deeper into error from child processes you *might* need to get stdout as well - not all processes consistently use stderr for their errors. Also some other stdout-only messages can be useful for build failure analysis as well.

Answer (score -1):

When debugging, it is also worth to look out for synchronization irregularities, where part of the stderr message may be **missing**!
[image]